# Extracting tensor data with index in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, data-manipulation, tensor

I would like to have the tensor indexed a certain way.

Suppose my data, tensor X shaped `(1, 3, 16, 9)` is

```
tensor([[[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  5.,  6.],
      [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
      [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  6.,  7.,  8.],
      [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  4.,  0.,  7.,  8.,  0.],
      [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  5.,  6.,  0.,  9., 10.],
      [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  9., 10., 11.],
      [ 2.,  3.,  4.,  6.,  7.,  8., 10., 11., 12.],
      [ 3.,  4.,  0.,  7.,  8.,  0., 11., 12.,  0.],
      [ 0.,  5.,  6.,  0.,  9., 10.,  0., 13., 14.],
      [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  9., 10., 11., 13., 14., 15.],
      [ 6.,  7.,  8., 10., 11., 12., 14., 15., 16.],
      [ 7.,  8.,  0., 11., 12.,  0., 15., 16.,  0.],
      [ 0.,  9., 10.,  0., 13., 14.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
      [ 9., 10., 11., 13., 14., 15.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
      [10., 11., 12., 14., 15., 16.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
      [11., 12.,  0., 15., 16.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

     [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 17., 18.,  0., 21., 22.],
      [ 0.,  0.,  0., 17., 18., 19., 21., 22., 23.],
      [ 0.,  0.,  0., 18., 19., 20., 22., 23., 24.],
      [ 0.,  0.,  0., 19., 20.,  0., 23., 24.,  0.],
      [ 0., 17., 18.,  0., 21., 22.,  0., 25., 26.],
      [17., 18., 19., 21., 22., 23., 25., 26., 27.],
      [18., 19., 20., 22., 23., 24., 26., 27., 28.],
      [19., 20.,  0., 23., 24.,  0., 27., 28.,  0.],
      [ 0., 21., 22.,  0., 25., 26.,  0., 29., 30.],
      [21., 22., 23., 25., 26., 27., 29., 30., 31.],
      [22., 23., 24., 26., 27., 28., 30., 31., 32.],
      [23., 24.,  0., 27., 28.,  0., 31., 32.,  0.],
      [ 0., 25., 26.,  0., 29., 30.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
      [25., 26., 27., 29., 30., 31.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
      [26., 27., 28., 30., 31., 32.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
      [27., 28.,  0., 31., 32.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

     [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 33., 34.,  0., 37., 38.],
      [ 0.,  0.,  0., 33., 34., 35., 37., 38., 39.],
      [ 0.,  0.,  0., 34., 35., 36., 38., 39., 40.],
      [ 0.,  0.,  0., 35., 36.,  0., 39., 40.,  0.],
      [ 0., 33., 34.,  0., 37., 38.,  0., 41., 42.],
      [33., 34., 35., 37., 38., 39., 41., 42., 43.],
      [34., 35., 36., 38., 39., 40., 42., 43., 44.],
      [35., 36.,  0., 39., 40.,  0., 43., 44.,  0.],
      [ 0., 37., 38.,  0., 41., 42.,  0., 45., 46.],
      [37., 38., 39., 41., 42., 43., 45., 46., 47.],
      [38., 39., 40., 42., 43., 44., 46., 47., 48.],
      [39., 40.,  0., 43., 44.,  0., 47., 48.,  0.],
      [ 0., 41., 42.,  0., 45., 46.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
      [41., 42., 43., 45., 46., 47.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
      [42., 43., 44., 46., 47., 48.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
      [43., 44.,  0., 47., 48.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]]]
```

I would like to have those rows where `(row_index % n) == i` (say `n = 4` and `i = 0 to 3`) is saved in another tensor `Y`.

For example, for the data `X[0][0]`:

```
[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  5.,  6.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  6.,  7.,  8.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  4.,  0.,  7.,  8.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  5.,  6.,  0.,  9., 10.],
 [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  9., 10., 11.],
 [ 2.,  3.,  4.,  6.,  7.,  8., 10., 11., 12.],
 [ 3.,  4.,  0.,  7.,  8.,  0., 11., 12.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  5.,  6.,  0.,  9., 10.,  0., 13., 14.],
 [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  9., 10., 11., 13., 14., 15.],
 [ 6.,  7.,  8., 10., 11., 12., 14., 15., 16.],
 [ 7.,  8.,  0., 11., 12.,  0., 15., 16.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  9., 10.,  0., 13., 14.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 9., 10., 11., 13., 14., 15.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [10., 11., 12., 14., 15., 16.,  0.,  0.,  0.],      
 [11., 12.,  0., 15., 16.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]
```

I would like to have a tensor containing the following data, which is basically collection of the rows where `row_index % 4 == 0` (here `i = 0`):

```
[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  5.,  6.],
 [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  5.,  6.,  0.,  9., 10.],
 [ 0.,  5.,  6.,  0.,  9., 10.,  0., 13., 14.],
 [ 0.,  9., 10.,  0., 13., 14.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]
```

Similarly, where `i = 1`, `row_index % 4 == i` will look like:

```
[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
 [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  9., 10., 11.],
 [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  9., 10., 11., 13., 14., 15.],
 [ 9., 10., 11., 13., 14., 15.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]
```

when `i = 2`,  `row_index % 4 == i`:

```
[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  6.,  7.,  8.],
 [ 2.,  3.,  4.,  6.,  7.,  8., 10., 11., 12.],
 [ 6.,  7.,  8., 10., 11., 12., 14., 15., 16.],
 [10., 11., 12., 14., 15., 16.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]
```

when `i = 3`,  `row_index % 4 == i`:

```
[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  4.,  0.,  7.,  8.,  0.],
 [ 3.,  4.,  0.,  7.,  8.,  0., 11., 12.,  0.],
 [ 7.,  8.,  0., 11., 12.,  0., 15., 16.,  0.],
 [11., 12.,  0., 15., 16.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]
```

I have tried hard coding it and it doesn't seem practical when the data becomes larger and the size becomes dynamic and I assume that there would be a better way to come about it.

```
temp0 = data[0][0][0][:] 
temp1 = data[0][0][4][:]
temp2 = data[0][0][8][:]
temp3 = data[0][0][12][:]
temp = torch.stack([temp0,temp1,temp2,temp3],dim = 0)
```

Also, it would be great if the result can come back in one tensor like :

```
tensor Y = ([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  5.,  6.],
              [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  5.,  6.,  0.,  9., 10.],
              [ 0.,  5.,  6.,  0.,  9., 10.,  0., 13., 14.],
              [ 0.,  9., 10.,  0., 13., 14.,  0.,  0.,  0.]], 

             [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
              [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  9., 10., 11.],
              [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  9., 10., 11., 13., 14., 15.],
              [ 9., 10., 11., 13., 14., 15.,  0.,  0.,  0.]], 
   
             [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  6.,  7.,  8.],
              [ 2.,  3.,  4.,  6.,  7.,  8., 10., 11., 12.],
              [ 6.,  7.,  8., 10., 11., 12., 14., 15., 16.],
              [10., 11., 12., 14., 15., 16.,  0.,  0.,  0.]], 

             [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  4.,  0.,  7.,  8.,  0.],
              [ 3.,  4.,  0.,  7.,  8.,  0., 11., 12.,  0.],
              [ 7.,  8.,  0., 11., 12.,  0., 15., 16.,  0.],
              [11., 12.,  0., 15., 16.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by first constructing a tensor containing the selected rows, then using [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) to assemble the final tensor.

Assuming we two *list*s `I` and `N` containing the values of `i` and `n` respectively:

```
I = [0, 1, 2, 3]
N = [4, 4, 4, 4]
```

First we construct the index tensor:

```
>>> index = torch.stack([(torch.arange(16) % n == i).nonzero() for i, n in zip(I, N)])
tensor([[[ 0],
         [ 4],
         [ 8],
         [12]],

        [[ 1],
         [ 5],
         [ 9],
         [13]],

        [[ 2],
         [ 6],
         [10],
         [14]],

        [[ 3],
         [ 7],
         [11],
         [15]]])
```

Then some expanding and reshaping is required:

```
>>> index_ = index[None].flatten(1,2).expand(X.size(0), -1, X.size(-1))
tensor([[[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
         [ 4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4],
         [ 8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8],
         [12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12],
         [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
         [ 5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5],
         [ 9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9],
         [13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13],
         [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2],
         [ 6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6],
         [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
         [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
         [ 3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3],
         [ 7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7],
         [11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11],
         [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15]]])
```

As a rule of thumb, we want `index_` to have the same number of dimensions as `X`.

Now we can apply `torch.gather` and reshape to the final form:

```
>>> X.gather(1, index_).reshape(len(X), *index.shape[:2], -1)
tensor([[[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  5.,  6.],
          [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  5.,  6.,  0.,  9., 10.],
          [ 0.,  5.,  6.,  0.,  9., 10.,  0., 13., 14.],
          [ 0.,  9., 10.,  0., 13., 14.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
          [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  9., 10., 11.],
          [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  9., 10., 11., 13., 14., 15.],
          [ 9., 10., 11., 13., 14., 15.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  6.,  7.,  8.],
          [ 2.,  3.,  4.,  6.,  7.,  8., 10., 11., 12.],
          [ 6.,  7.,  8., 10., 11., 12., 14., 15., 16.],
          [10., 11., 12., 14., 15., 16.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  4.,  0.,  7.,  8.,  0.],
          [ 3.,  4.,  0.,  7.,  8.,  0., 11., 12.,  0.],
          [ 7.,  8.,  0., 11., 12.,  0., 15., 16.,  0.],
          [11., 12.,  0., 15., 16.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]]])
```

---

This method can be extended to batch tensors:

```
>>> index = torch.stack([(torch.arange(16) % n == i).nonzero() for i, n in zip(I, N)])
>>> index_  = index[None,None].flatten(2,3).expand(X.size(0), X.size(1), -1, X.size(-1))

>>> X.gather(2, index_).reshape(*X.shape[:2], *index.shape[:2], -1)
```

Comment: I get this error when I run "X.gather(1, index_).reshape(len(X), *index.shape[:2], -1)" :

RuntimeError: Index tensor must have the same number of dimensions as input tensor.

Also is there a good article or course to look up, because I can't seem to visualize the data manipulation functions and still struggling to comprehend your code  
Thank you

Comment: What is the shape of your input tensor `X`? I will edit my question if details on the broadcasting/reshaping approach.

Comment: Thank you for getting back. The batch extension works and it seems expanding the index_ did the trick for the first part.
"index_ = index_.view(index_.size(0),1,index_.size(1),index_.size(2))
index_ = index_.expand(-1,X.size(1),-1,-1)".
Thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

First, to get each patrition you can try this:

```
import torch

data = torch.tensor([[[[0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 2., 0., 5., 6.],
                       [0., 0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 5., 6., 7.],
                       [0., 0., 0., 2., 3., 4., 6., 7., 8.],
                       [0., 0., 0., 3., 4., 0., 7., 8., 0.],
                       [0., 1., 2., 0., 5., 6., 0., 9., 10.],
                       [1., 2., 3., 5., 6., 7., 9., 10., 11.],
                       [2., 3., 4., 6., 7., 8., 10., 11., 12.],
                       [3., 4., 0., 7., 8., 0., 11., 12., 0.],
                       [0., 5., 6., 0., 9., 10., 0., 13., 14.],
                       [5., 6., 7., 9., 10., 11., 13., 14., 15.],
                       [6., 7., 8., 10., 11., 12., 14., 15., 16.],
                       [7., 8., 0., 11., 12., 0., 15., 16., 0.],
                       [0., 9., 10., 0., 13., 14., 0., 0., 0.],
                       [9., 10., 11., 13., 14., 15., 0., 0., 0.],
                       [10., 11., 12., 14., 15., 16., 0., 0., 0.],
                       [11., 12., 0., 15., 16., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

                      [[0., 0., 0., 0., 17., 18., 0., 21., 22.],
                       [0., 0., 0., 17., 18., 19., 21., 22., 23.],
                       [0., 0., 0., 18., 19., 20., 22., 23., 24.],
                       [0., 0., 0., 19., 20., 0., 23., 24., 0.],
                       [0., 17., 18., 0., 21., 22., 0., 25., 26.],
                       [17., 18., 19., 21., 22., 23., 25., 26., 27.],
                       [18., 19., 20., 22., 23., 24., 26., 27., 28.],
                       [19., 20., 0., 23., 24., 0., 27., 28., 0.],
                       [0., 21., 22., 0., 25., 26., 0., 29., 30.],
                       [21., 22., 23., 25., 26., 27., 29., 30., 31.],
                       [22., 23., 24., 26., 27., 28., 30., 31., 32.],
                       [23., 24., 0., 27., 28., 0., 31., 32., 0.],
                       [0., 25., 26., 0., 29., 30., 0., 0., 0.],
                       [25., 26., 27., 29., 30., 31., 0., 0., 0.],
                       [26., 27., 28., 30., 31., 32., 0., 0., 0.],
                       [27., 28., 0., 31., 32., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

                      [[0., 0., 0., 0., 33., 34., 0., 37., 38.],
                       [0., 0., 0., 33., 34., 35., 37., 38., 39.],
                       [0., 0., 0., 34., 35., 36., 38., 39., 40.],
                       [0., 0., 0., 35., 36., 0., 39., 40., 0.],
                       [0., 33., 34., 0., 37., 38., 0., 41., 42.],
                       [33., 34., 35., 37., 38., 39., 41., 42., 43.],
                       [34., 35., 36., 38., 39., 40., 42., 43., 44.],
                       [35., 36., 0., 39., 40., 0., 43., 44., 0.],
                       [0., 37., 38., 0., 41., 42., 0., 45., 46.],
                       [37., 38., 39., 41., 42., 43., 45., 46., 47.],
                       [38., 39., 40., 42., 43., 44., 46., 47., 48.],
                       [39., 40., 0., 43., 44., 0., 47., 48., 0.],
                       [0., 41., 42., 0., 45., 46., 0., 0., 0.],
                       [41., 42., 43., 45., 46., 47., 0., 0., 0.],
                       [42., 43., 44., 46., 47., 48., 0., 0., 0.],
                       [43., 44., 0., 47., 48., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]]])

print(data.shape)

n, i = 4, 0
indices = [index for index in range(data.shape[2]) if index % n == i]
print(data[0, 0, indices])
```

For the combination of those tensors you can try using:

```
n = 4
result = []
for i in range(n):
    indices = [index for index in range(data.shape[2]) if index % n == i]
    result.append(data[0, 0, indices])

final = torch.stack(result, dim=0)
```

Comment: Great, let me know if that works for you. If it does, please mark this question as answered :)